# CardViews Refuses to Populate the RecyclerView and How to prevent a method from being called after Screen rotation

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am using Volley to fetch json whose data is used to populate Cardviews which in turn is used to populate Recyclerviews.

**This is the MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";



    //Creating a list of posts
    private List<PostItems> mPostItemsList;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "Device rotated and onCreate called");

        //Initializing Views
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.post_recycler);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        //Initializing the postlist
        mPostItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new PostAdapter(mPostItemsList, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(this)) {
            //Caling method to get data
            getData();
        } else {
            final Context mContext;
            mContext = this;
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.alert_titl);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.alert_mess);
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_posi, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(mContext)) {
                        alertDialogBuilder.show();
                    } else {
                        getData();
                    }


                }
            });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_nega, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();

                }
            });
            alertDialogBuilder.show();

        }

    }

    //This method will get data from the web api
    private void getData(){


        Log.d(TAG, "getData called");
        //Showing progress dialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(this.getResources().getString(R.string.load_post));
        mProgressDialog.show();

        //Creating a json request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(ConfigPost.GET_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called");
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                            mProgressDialog.hide();
                        }
                        /*progressDialog.dismiss();*/


                        //calling method to parse json array
                        parseData(response);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array){
        Log.d(TAG, "Parsing array");

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            PostItems postItem = new PostItems();
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                postItem.setPost_title(jsonObject.getString(ConfigPost.TAG_POST_TITLE));
                postItem.setPost_body(jsonObject.getString(ConfigPost.TAG_POST_BODY));

 } catch (JSONException w) {
                w.printStackTrace();
            }
            mPostItemsList.add(postItem);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy called");
        if (mProgressDialog != null){
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d(TAG, "mProgress dialog dismissed");

        }
    }
```

**And this is the Adapter**

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;

    //List of posts
    private List<PostItems> mPostItems;



   public PostAdapter(List<PostItems> postItems, Context context) {
       super();

       //Getting all posts
       this.mPostItems = postItems;
       this.mContext = context;
   }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.post_summ, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PostItems postList = mPostItems.get(position);

        holder.postTitle.setText(postList.getPost_title());
        holder.postBody.setText(postList.getPost_body());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        //Return the number of items in the data set
        return mPostItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView postTitle, postBody;

        public ViewHolder (View postView) {
            super(postView);
            postTitle = (TextView) postView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            postBody = (TextView) postView.findViewById(R.id.post_body);
        }
    }


}
```

I am having three problems with these codes:

1. After the json data have been parsed; the activity's layout is never populated with the cardviews until the screen has timed out and I press a button to bring it up again. But, if while I am waiting for the screen to time out, that I press the power key and unlocks the phone, the cardviews won't show. So, it only shows when the screen times out on it own and I press a button to bring it up again.
2. After or before the cardviews has been displayed, if a configuration change occurs e.g rotation, `getData()` gets called and then `PostItems` are the reloaded and problem 1 happens again. Is there anyway I can prevent `getData` from being called when the activity is recreated?
3. When the app starts up, it checks for internet connection. If not available it displays a dialog to **Retry** or **Cancel**. But if available `getData` is called and `mProgressDialog` is shown. Now while `mProgressDialog` is still being shown that Internet becomes unavailable, the Activity can't detect and `mProgressDialog` keeps showing till eternity. I don't know how t check for internet connectivity while the `mProgressDialog` is showing or the JSON is still loading.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed some basic concepts of `RecyclerView`, orientation changes and network monitor.

1. While you `setAdapter` you're list is empty. You can solve this either by calling `setAdapter` after you get data from web service or after you get data `notifyItemChanged` should be called.
2. To resolve your orientation changes you have to handle in `OnConfigurationChanged`.
3. You probably define the timeout for your network call, so basically that should take care if network disconnect. Else you have to monitor the network change. [Refer this](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges)

Comment: you have to save the arraylist with filled data in onSavedInstance method. when you setting the adapter with the arraylist you have to check the araaylist should not be null and greater then zero then set the adapter

Comment: May I know for which issue you're suggesting this?

Comment: After the ortientation change when you are lossing the data in the recyler view

Comment: @Amit, I thought Volley auto-caches it's responses and the key to solving problem 2 is to call `getData` only when savedinstancestate is null? Am I wrong or right?

Comment: yeahh you can check the condition if arraylist is not equal to null and arraylist size is greater then 0 then set the adapter.

Comment: @Kelvin, where or the code should I call `setAdapter` or which parameter should I pass the `adapter.notifyItemChanged()` ?